# liquibase won't respond when the system trying to boot

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I'm trying to integrate liquibase in to an existing project with existing database (PostgreSQL).

when I'm trying to start the system, I don't see liquibase trying to do any action.

this is the datasource bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url.intguard}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username.intguard}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password.intguard}" />
    </bean>
```

LiquibaseCofing:

```
@ContextConfiguration
public class LiquibaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/database/changelog.xml");
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return liquibase;
    }

}
```

liquibase-changelog.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet author="John" id="someUniqueId">
        <addColumn tableName="users">
            <column name="address" type="varchar(255)" />
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I know that LiquibaseConfig bean is being invoked when the system is starting,
please help me catch what I'm missing,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you need to set property with `SpringLiquibase.shouldRun(true)`.

Try to debug method `SpringLiquibase#afterPropertiesSet()` or at least try to add logging for package `liquibase.integration.spring` to see if there is some mention about invocation.

Comment: Isn't this property `true` by default?